# I want to add randomly a to z in columns using loops.how can i do this?

Tags: pandas, dataset, rows

I want to add randomly a to z in columns using loops.how can i do this?

```
 I want to add randomly a to z in columns using loops.how can i do this?
example:
this my columns
     name
0    Tim
1    Mit
2    Jason
3    Jasim
4    Sible



Expected results: 
     name
0    Tima
1    Mitb
2    Jasonc
3    Jasim
4    Siblex
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
import string
# create a list of characters
choice_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase)
# generate sudo random letter from the list
rand = np.random.choice(choice_list, len(df))
# append strings
df['name_new'] = df['name'].values + rand

    name name_new
0    Tim     Tima
1    Mit     Mite
2  Jason   Jasonz
3  Jasim   Jasimp
4  Sible   Siblec
```

## update

```
import numpy as np
import string
# create a list of characters
choice_list = list(string.ascii_lowercase)

# create a rand sample of your dataframe
random_sample = df['name'].sample(3) # your sample size

# generate sudo random letter from the list    
rand = np.random.choice(choice_list, len(random_sample))

# append strings using iloc
df.iloc[random_sample.index, 0] = random_sample.values + rand


     name
0    Timy
1    Mitp
2  Jasony
3   Jasim
4   Sible
```

Comment: I want to give a  range.how can I do that?

Comment: @tosifulislam what do you mean by range?

Comment: suppose my columns have 1000 data. I want to randomly add  letter to only 200 of the data.

Comment: What is the `address` column? Your sample df only has `name` but this will work with any column that has a data type of string

Comment: my address columns is also string

Comment: So...what is the issue?

Comment: the random letter added in the name column like my sample but it does not add any letter in address column where the address is also string

Comment: What index is your address column?

Comment: Address is the index of my column.

Comment: Address is the name what is the index (i.e., location: is it 0 or 1 or 2 ...)

Comment: index is 4 brother

Comment: Change 0 in the `iloc` to 4: `df.iloc[random_sample.index, 4]`

Comment: it's working..thank you so much, brother. I am a beginner that's why I am facing this problem ...again thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't use loops here; you can get the same result with a `.apply()` call with a lambda function inside. `.apply()` performs the same function on every row of your data, and lambdas let you create anonymous functions.

If you have a string containing all the letters you want to add, you can then use the `choice` function from the `random` module to pick a letter at random and add it to the string.

The lambda function looks like this: `lambda x: x + choice(letters)`. Essentially, it says that for any value `x`, it will return `x` plus a randomly chosen letter.

Assuming that your column of names is called `data`, here is an example of the above:

```
from random import choice

letters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

data.apply(lambda x: x + choice(letters))
```

Comment: but i want to add letter randomly in my data.but your code add letter all of my data.

Comment: Then the best solution is Chris' answer above.